# How to prove $\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can anyone suggest the method of computing 
$$\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}\quad ?$$

---

My trial is following

first set $t =\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ which gives $x=\frac{1-t}{t+1}$ 
Then 
\begin{align}
dx = \frac{2}{(1+t)^2} dt, \quad [x,0,1] \rightarrow [t,1, 0]
\end{align}
[Thanks to  @Alexey Burdin, i found what i do wrong in substitution]

then the integral reduces to
\begin{align} 
\int^{0}_1 \ln(t)\frac{2}{1-t^2} dt 
\end{align}
How one can obtain above integral?

Please post an answer if you know the answer to this integral or the other methods to evaluate above integral. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the upper limit of the given integral actually, $1$ or $\infty$? I see both $[x,0,\mathbf{\infty}]\to[t,1,−1]$ and $\int_0^\mathbf{1}$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, the upper limit of the given integral is $1$. $\int_0^1 \cdots dx$.

Comment: So why do we $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+x}{1-x}$, $~~~~~x$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Oh i see the wrong point!. Thanks @Alexey Burdin

Comment: i could provide another approacah using contour integration if you are interested...

Comment: @tired, Oh goods! Various approach is very instructive to my self-study on this integral!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the convergence issue aside, I'll compute the integral formally using power series.

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}\frac{\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}}{x}=\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}\end{eqnarray}
Integrating termwise,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}
\end{eqnarray}
Using the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$, we have the required sum is $\displaystyle2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** By the change of variable 
$$
t =\frac{1-x}{1+x}
$$ you get
$$
\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) \frac{dx}{x}=-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2} dt=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1t^{2n}\:\ln t \:dt=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{4}.
$$

Comment: Is the last equality really an equality?

Comment: @AlexFok There is a 2 missing in both last steps, but multiplying the series by 2 will fix it.